# A complicated lemma from Munkres's Topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I don't understand the following lemma of the book Topology by J Munkres :

[image]

1- If a set $A$ with the mentioned properties exists there must be an example for it and so, it could help to understand both the lemma and the proof better? I tried some different types of uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ but they don't work thus another question is

2- How to we know for sure (a proof) that there exists an $\Omega$ such that it is the smallest element of $C$ for which the section of $C$ by $\Omega$ is uncountable?

I would appreciate any simple clear detailed explanation.

PS. **Definition.** Let $X$ be a well-ordered set. Given $\alpha \in X$, let $S_{\alpha}$ denote the set $$S_{\alpha} = {\{x \ | \ x \in X \ \text{and} \ x < \alpha}\}.$$ It is called the section of $X$ by $\alpha$.

Comment: Ordinals are well-ordered. Hence the minimum exists.

Comment: @Liebe would you mind to include what do you mean with the section $S_{\Omega}$?

Comment: The construction is indirect, as a minimum. It is essentially unique.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, the minimum exist in any subset, yes. But the minimum exist with the mentioned properties is the question I've asked.

Comment: Munkres' construction is probably the simplest description of such a set $A$ that doesn't require you to learn a fair bit of elementary formal set theory first.  For your second question, the definition of $C$ ensures that $\{x\in C:S_x\text{ is uncountable}\}$ is non-empty. $C$ is well-ordered, so this non-empty set has a least element, which we call $\Omega$.

Comment: $\Omega$ is another name for the least uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$, and the set $A$ is just $\omega_1$ together with the element $\omega_1$ itself — that is, $A = \omega_1 \cup \{\omega_1\} = \omega_1 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

So $B$ is a well-ordered set that is uncountable. I think Munkres showed the existence of such a set before this lemma.

Define $C$ as $\{1,2\} \times B$ in the lexicographical ordering. This is also a well-order by previous results.

If $b \in B$ then for all $x\in B$, we have $(1,x) < (2,b)$ and so $S_{(2,b)}$ is uncountable.

So define $U$ to be the set of all elements $x$ of $C$ that have $S_x$ uncountable. We have just shown that $U$ is non-empty, so there is a minimum $m \in U$.

So $S_m = \{x \in C: x < m \}$ (order taken in $C$ of course) is uncountable, as $m \in U$. And any $x \in S_m$ has a countable section because otherwise it would contradict the minimality of $m$. So $A = S_m \cup \{m\}$ is the required uncountable well-ordered set (with $m$ as the max) in the inherited order from $C$.

These properties define $A$ up to order isomorphism (so it's essentially unique) and indeed it can be shown that no subset of the real line in its standard order can be isomorphic to it.

Comment: Munkers says "Zermelo in 1904 proved that if A is a set, there exists an order relation on A that's well-ordering". It is left without a proof in the book. What I can't understand is that whatever A is, it is a subset of ${\{1,2}\} \times \mathbb {R^n}$ and what's is its explicit set?

Comment: @Liebe you cannot define an explicit well-order on $\mathbb{R}$ (ironically this *can* be proved!). So it's a subset of $\{1,2\} \times \mathbb{R}$, possibly, **if** we have a well-order on the reals, which we don't have explicitly. Zermelo showed there is one using the Axiom of Choice, as said. The Hartogs' number mentioned in the other comments is a way to prove there exists a well-order on an uncountable set (but it's again not explicit) without using Choice. Using Choice (which Munkres assumes) it's easier to just use a well-order "from thin air" using that.

Answer (score 0):

This lemma is demonstrating one of the more bizarre consequences of the fact that the axiom of choice lets us well-order any set. The consequence is that: There is a minimum uncountable ordinal.

Ordinal numbers are like cardinal numbers except they only apply to well-ordered sets, and give a finer distinction than cardinality for such sets. Two sets are of the same ordinal, if they are of the same cardinal *and* there exists an order isomorphism. That is, a one-to-one and onto function (thus showing their cardinal equivalence) that is also an order preserving map in *both* directions.

In this lemma, the ordinal of the set $A$ is the 2nd to least uncountable ordinal.

Comment: Is it bizarre that there are uncountable ordinals? More bizarre still that  $\Bbb R$ should be a countable union of countable sets, which is consistent with $\neg$ AC.

Comment: While this argument makes use of the axiom of choice, the existence of a well-ordered set with the properties required of $A$ does not depend $\mathsf{AC}$. Using choice here is merely a convenience.

Comment: As a note, if you're wanting to see an explicit example, you're going to be out of luck because that is not actually possible! The reason is that the axiom of choice is not constructive, hence the things it declares to be true cannot necessarily be demonstrated (and indeed, to my knowledge, no one has given an explicit well-ordering of the real numbers, which should be possible if AC is true).

Comment: @BrianO $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a countable union of countable sets, because then it would be countable (I recall proving the theorem that countable union of countable sets is countable in set theory), maybe you meant countable cartesian product? (Which need not be countable)

Comment: @Justin: The reasoning in your last comment is incorrect, since the existence of $\omega_1$ does not depend on the axiom of choice.

Comment: So we can't construct an example for such a set (A) in this lemma?

Comment: @j Justin: BrianO meant exactly what he wrote: in the absence of the axiom of choice the union of countably many countable sets need not be countable.

Comment: @Liebe: The lemma gives a construction of $A$.

Comment: It seems you are right about this (very interesting): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Yes it gives a construction and when it exists means it must be such $A = {\{1,2}\} \times B_1$ and $B_1 \subset \mathbb R$. So what is $B_1$ **explicitly** if it is a collection of numbers?

Comment: $C$ was, _a priori_ a well-ordered set, $\mathbb{R}$ is not well-ordered (it is linearly ordered though).

Comment: Since $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, you can take $B$ to be $\Bbb R$. You won't be able to define an explicit well-ordering of $\Bbb R$, but Munkres is assuming the axiom of choice, so you know that there is one. The rest of the construction is explicit. If you want something more explicit, avoiding the axiom of choice, you'll need to learn something about the ordinal, which means learning more set theory than is usually taught in undergraduate courses.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, whatever I know books about set theory none of them discuss those subjects. "*If you want something more explicit, avoiding the axiom of choice, [...] than is usually taught in undergraduate courses.*", could you please let me know an easy to understand book to find out about an answer to my question? Thanks.

Comment: @Liebe: [This one](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Edition-Revised-Expanded-Mathematics/dp/0824779150) is good, and I doubt that you'll find one that's much easier to understand. Be aware, though, that the relevant material is quite technical, even after you work through a rigorous development of what Munkres calls $\Omega$, you probably won't feel that you have a good intuitive picture of it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I found the book! The book seems very nice. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Liebe: You're welcome.